# Scrollable page with percent-width navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Goal: create scrolling content overlaid by an equally wide navbar. Example html could look like:

```
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

Criteria:

1. `.content` fills a percent width of `.scrollable`, and is horizontally centered
2. `.scrollable` should have scrollbars
3. `.navbar` is exactly as wide as `.content`, centered exactly atop `.content`
4. Scrollbar width is treated as unknown (handled dynamically)
5. Avoid javascript `onscroll` event, `requestAnimationFrame`, `setInterval`, etc. **Ideally no js at all!**

The intuitive approach of setting `.navbar` to `position: absolute` and giving it the same width as `.content` *fails* - the scrollbar causes a discrepancy in dimensions. (Circumventing this does not seem trivial...)

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%; height: 80%; left: 10%; top: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0;
  overflow: hidden visible;
}
.scrollable > .content {
  width: 80%; margin: 60px auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); text-align: center;
}
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%; bottom: 0; width: 80%; height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3); color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="content">abcd<br/><br/><br/>abcd<br/><br/><br/>abcd<br/><br/><br/>abcd<br/><br/><br/>abcd<br/><br/><br/>abcd<br/><br/><br/>abcd<br/><br/><br/>abcd<br/><br/><br/>abcd<br/><br/><br/>abcd<br/><br/><br/></div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">I am navbar</div>
</div>
```

The issue here is that `.content` takes up a percentage width of `.scrollable`'s width *minus its scrollbar width*, whereas `.navbar` is set to a percentage width of `.scrollable` *including* its scrollbar width.

**What is the best way to get around this discrepancy?**

Answer (score 0):

check the answer in the codepen : https://codepen.io/the-wrong-guy/pen/vYLzRZZ

And you should use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` to fix the navbar at the top

Comment: This looks very close to what I'm interested in - but in your codepen the `.scrollable` element is actually not scrollable (even though I didn't list this as a criteria I was hoping it was implied by the class name). Your example looks like it works, but only because the `html` element, not `.scrollable`, is scrolling. (It works even if I add `.scrollable { overflow: hidden; }`)

Comment: yeah i forgot to remove the `overflow-x`, but it will scrollable if only the content overflows i think that's what you want

Comment: Would you mind trying to update your code? (And maybe include it as a snippet in your answer! More accessible that way.)